# Send a ZIP file for a server using kotlin and retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin

I looking for a way to send a zip file for a server using retrofit in kotlin. Some functions are deprecated that's make this more dificulte. When I star the request the response is NULL, there is no error.
That is the function who start the request:

```
fun sendZipeFile() {
            val retrofitClient = NetworkUtils
                .getRetrofitInstance("http://url.com")
            val sendZipeFileEndPoint = retrofitClient.create(SendZipeFile::class.java)

            var file = File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/file.zip")
            val requestImageFile = file?.asRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaType())
            val callback = startZipeFileUpload.zipeFileUpload("application/zip","Atualização", requestImageFile, "0.0.2")
           

            callback.enqueue(object : Callback<UploadZipFile> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<UploadZipFile>, t: Throwable) {

                    t.message
                    t.fillInStackTrace()

                }
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<UploadZipFile>, response: Response<UploadZipFile>) {
                        val responseString = response.body()

                }



            })

        }
```

Below is an interface

```
interface SendZipeFile{
    @Headers("Content-Type: multipart/form-data")

    @Multipart
    @POST("updateModelsAndParameters/" +
            "")
    fun zipeFileUpload(
        @Header("Content-Type")  contentType: String?,
        @Part("description")  description: String?,
        @Part("Zip") file: RequestBody?,
        @Part("flag")flag: String?,

    ): Call<UploadZipFile>


}
```

And the data class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class UploadZipFile(
    @SerializedName("status_code") var statusCode: Int? = null,
    @SerializedName("message") var message: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("elapsed_ms") var elapsedMs: Double? = null,
    @SerializedName("response") var resposta: Boolean? = null,
)
```

Comment: You will not have access to that file on Android 11+, unless your app is the one that put the file in `Downloads/`.

Comment: I am not working with Android 11. I am working with API 28. But thanks!